# What is the Java returning null equivalent in C++?

Tags: c++, return

I already know Java and am trying to learn C++ for for some other reasons. In a method in Java, if you don't have anything to return or there is an unreachable return line according to your logic but you just want to make the compiler happy, you just return `null`. For example:

```
public static int[] /* This can be any Object, and returning null would work */ 5() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if(i == 5) {
            return new int[]{5}; // I don't know why you would want to do this, but I 
                                 // can't think of a better example.
        }
    }

    // The compiler will give an error because there is 
    // no return statement, even though it is guaranteed 
    // to return {5}. So, for convenience, do this:

    return null; 
}
```

However, if I do `return NULL` or even `return nullptr` in C++, it just gives an error. Is there any way I can get around this?

Comment: What is the return type of your function?

Comment: Any object there is.

Comment: In C++, only pointers can be NULL, not objects (unless the object can be constructed from it.

Comment: You can just throw an exception. That will please the compiler, and as a bonus, give you some useful debug info in case the statement ever _does_ get reached.

Comment: Just FYI: Unlike Java, C++ doesn't make it mandatory to add a return statement at the end.

Comment: Then what happens when it reaches there?

Comment: Java has objects everywhere. Objects on the heap. You could return a pointer to an array `std::unique_ptr<std::array<int, 5>>` and then you return `nullptr`. What does `new int[]{5}` do in java? Or maybe `std::optional` has better semantics for your use case.

Comment: @nexus As far as I understand, return statements are checked at runtime and not compile-time in c++, so if indeed your control reaches end of method and doesn't return anything, you'll get an error. But if you handle return statements in your logic itself, there's no need to add a return statement at the end.

Comment: If control would fall off a non-void function without a return, the behaviour of the program is undefined. A C++ compiler can treat your above function identically to `int * five(){ return new int[1] {5}; }`

Comment: @prakasht that's not true at all, if a C++ function has a return type the *every* return must return a value of that type.  This is checked at compile time, and you will get a compiler error if it isn't so.  That includes leaving out a `return` statement at the end of the function.

Comment: @MarkRansom no, return is not required, it's just UB to leave a (non-void) function without a `return` or `throw`. Your compiler may *warn* about a lack of return, and you might treat warnings as errors, but the language allows it.

Comment: @Caleth I thought typing in C++ was strong enough to disallow that possibility, but a quick test shows I'm wrong: http://ideone.com/E0C5cq  For sure any return statement must return the proper type or something convertible to it.

Comment: Yes @MarkRansom, also see http://ideone.com/HjuufB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like others have pointed out, there is `nullptr`. However returning a `nullptr` means your return value is a pointer which means you most likely have a heap allocation inside your function that you probably don't need.

Since C++ 17 we have [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) which you could use as a return type for your function.

Given any non-reference return type `T` you can change that return type to `std::optional<T>` and instead of a `nullptr` you return either `std::nullopt` or `{}`.

Example:

```
std::optional<std::string> foo(int x)
{
    if (x > 10)
        return "greater 10";

    return std::nullopt; // or return {}
}

int main()
{
    auto str = foo(12);

    if (str)  // check if str actually has a value or if it's null
        std::cout << *str;  // dereference to get the actual string
    else
        std::cout << "no string returned";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @jxh yes but that does a heap allocation aswell

Answer (score 3):

That depends on the return type of your function. If you return `int` you have to return an `int`. If you return an `int*` you can return `nullptr` etc. You only get to return `nullptr` for pointer types.

The reason you're allowed to return `null` when you return `Integer` in Java is because that type is implicitly already a reference/pointer type to an `int`.

In the case where you want to satisfy the compiler and return a "default" you can :

```
return {};
```

Note that in your case you really want to be returning `std::array`, your example doesn't do what you think it does, prefer `std::array` over C arrays.

Answer (score 1):

First of all in C++ if you will write the the function like this:

```cpp
struct Buffer {
};

Buffer calculateAndReturnBuffer() {
  // Some computations
  return Buffer{};
}
```

or something like this:

```cpp
struct Buffer {
};

Buffer calculateAndReturnBuffer() {
  // Some computations
  return {}; // C++ uniform initialization
}
```

Buffer object is returned by value, it mean that according the basic rules in C++, it will be copied (but due to batch of optimizations it will not)

If you will try return null in this case:

```cpp
struct Buffer {
};

Buffer calculateAndReturnBuffer() {
  // Some computations
  return nullptr; // or NULL
}
```

It will not work because nullptr is pointer type and NULL is define for 0 which is integer type and these objects cannot be converted to Buffer type
You will need to do the following:

```cpp
struct Buffer {
};

Buffer * calculateAndReturnBuffer() {
  // Some computations
  return nullptr; // or NULL
}
```

or something like this:

```cpp
struct Buffer {
};

Buffer * calculateAndReturnBuffer() {
  // Some computations
  return {}; // C++ uniform initialization
}
```

Back to your question ...
But in all cases you can use curly braces {}